# AttributeError: 'TwoCaptcha' object has no attribute 'recaptcha'

Tags: python

I try to make a solve bypass captcha but is not working.

```py
  
import requests
import bs4
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha
import os

TwoCaptcha_api_key = ""
renew_url = ""
renew_session = requests.session()
renew_request = renew_session.get(renew_url)
renew_content = renew_request._content
renew_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(renew_content, 'lxml')

renew_sitekey = renew_soup.find('div', {"class":"g-recaptcha"})['data-sitekey']

renew_token = renew_soup.find('input', {"name":"_token"})['value']
solve = TwoCaptcha(TwoCaptcha_api_key)
result = solve.recaptcha(
    sitekey=renew_sitekey,
    url=renew_url)

recaptcha_response = result['code']
postdata = {"username": "AAAAAAA", "g-recaptcha-response": f"{recaptcha_response}", "_token": f"{renew_token}" }
renew_post = renew_session.post(renew_url, data=postdata)
print(renew_post)
```

And i got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "", line 18, in <module><br>
    result = solve.recaptcha(<br>
AttributeError: 'TwoCaptcha' object has no attribute 'recaptcha'
```

Answer (score 15):

I'm guessing you are talking about this package https://pypi.org/project/2captcha-python/#solve-captcha to solve captcha.

I'm also guessing, you must have used some IDE to install this package which installed a wrong one. (https://pypi.org/project/TwoCaptcha/) which is the wrapper on the original one.

Remove the current incorrect package `pip uninstall TwoCaptcha` and install the correct one `pip install 2captcha-python`

Answer (score 1):

I am too late with my answer, but you probably have old version of package installed.

`pip3 install 2captcha-python`

Answer (score 0):

The function is called `solve_recaptcha()`, not `recaptcha`. (see [README])[1](https://github.com/My-kal/2Captcha)

Next time when you meet this error, you can look for the original code, the docs, or you can add a call to `dir()` to see the available members/methods:

```
solve = ...
print dir(solve)
```

Comment: What do you mean by solve_recaptha? because `solve.recaptcha` is TwoCaptcha.recaptcha

Comment: There's no such function (from what I see in github): https://github.com/My-kal/2Captcha/blob/master/twocaptcha/__init__.py#L14

Comment: AttributeError: 'TwoCaptcha' object has no attribute 'solve_recaptcha'

Answer (score 0):

In Ide pycharm or VS Go to terminal and past this code   "**pip3 install 2captcha-python**"
It will look like this
**PS C:\Users\PycharmProjects\test> pip3 install 2captcha-python**
It will solve your problem

Comment: Please provide some supporting information as to _how_ your answer solves the problem. Also, pasting the command in any terminal will work; it doesn't have to be in Idle, PyCharm, or VSCode. What do you mean by "it will look like this"? Do you mean that that's the output? That path is only a valid path on Windows.

Comment: This is also what the other answer already states.